# Measuring the instantaneous power consumption of phone

Tags: voltage, watts, android

We can get the instantaneous current consumption and battery voltage via Android's API. So if we multiply those things, can we get the instantaneous power consumption of device? (P=V.I)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Multiplying the voltage and current at any instant in time yields the power at that instant in time.